# select startdate enddate Date range highlight jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have using the following code i dont know how to highlight the selected dates, and how to add css for selected dates

Here my code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({               
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      autoclose: true,
      minDate:0,

      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "show" );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({               
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate:0,
      autoclose: true,


    });

  });
</script>


</head>
<body>

  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" value="19/04/2016">
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to" value="29/04/2016">
```

I need the highlight like the below image

[image]

Please help me how to highlight.
Thanks

Comment: If I reads this correctly, when a `#from` date and a `#to` date are selected, you want to highlight something. What exactly do you want to highlight?

Comment: I want to highlight( addClass -> background color.) the date between startdate and enddate.
Please check my attached screen sort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have fixed the issue now its working.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
var startDate = $('#reportFrom').val();
var endDate = $('#reportTo').val();
startDate = startDate.split('/');
endDate = endDate.split('/');
startDate = new Date(startDate[2], (startDate[1]-1), startDate[0]);
endDate = new Date(endDate[2], (endDate[1]-1), endDate[0]);

if ($.trim(startDate) != '' && $.trim(endDate) !='') {
  if(($.trim(startDate) == $.trim(date)) && ($.trim(endDate) == $.trim(date))) {
    return [true, 'dp-highlight dp-end-highlight dp-start-highlight'];
  }
  if($.trim(startDate) == $.trim(date)) {
    return [true, 'dp-highlight dp-start-highlight'];
  }
  if(date < endDate && date > startDate ) {
    return [true, 'dp-highlight'];
  }
  if($.trim(endDate) == $.trim(date)) {
    return [true, 'dp-highlight dp-end-highlight'];
  }

  return [true, ''];
}
}
```